# error in url the form codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
    <form role="form" action="<?=base_url("formulario_controller/recibirFormulario")?>" method="post"> </form>
```

I have a problem with the route of the form I check examples and so I saw how it has it but it marks me the error object not located.

Comment: whats the url out put of the form action have you set the base url in config.php

Comment: `<form action="http://localhost/code/formulario_controller/recibirFormulario" method="post">`   this

Comment: @LupithaYañezC. So is your controller filename Formulario_controller.php (With the 1st Letter capitalised ) and the class in the controller Formulario_controller? Also try changing your method name recibirFormularion to all lowercase in your form action.

Comment: @Lupitha Yanez C. did you gave base_url="localhost/code" in config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formulario_controller` must use the file and class naming conventions of CodeIgniter.

Controller file name must start with an upper case letter, eg. **Formulario_controller.php**

The class definition has the same requirement - upper case first letter

```
class Formulario_controller extends CI_Controller
{
  ...
}
```

[Documentation Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

A comment on controller naming: There is no reason to use `_controller` and doing so will make your URL's look kinda funny. It makes sense for models and views to use a suffix but not for controllers.

Answer (score -3):

Your form code should look like this.

```
<form role="form" action="<?=base_url()."formulario_controller/recibirFormulario";?>" method="post">
```

You have already set the base_url at the config file in CodeIgniter/Applciation/Config/config.php.

Comment: @Shahriar This is no different to the OPs original code except you moved the "formulario_controller/recibirFormulario" outside of the base_url() function. You do realise that base_url("formulario_controller/recibirFormulario") is completely allowed and even preferred in many casnes.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no reason not to use `base_url("formulario_controller/recibirFormulario")`. While your use is not "technically" wrong, it not an effective use of the function. It's also not the answer.  [base_url() documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url)